# Vertical alignment of LI with CSS, but with 1 px margin

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I need to align vertically text in horizontally arranged LI items, but the margin between them needs to be 1 px. If I use display:table-cell and border-spacing:1 px then the space between them ends up being 2 pixels. I wish I could just set "border-spacing-right:1px". Any ideas? Below is my code, where the first set doesn't even align, also in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/break68/SLDcU/3/

```
<style>
.nav1 li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height:40px;
width:50px;
background-color:#777;
margin-right:1px;
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding:2px;
}

.nav2 li {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height:40px;
width:50px;
margin-right:1px;
background-color:#777;
list-style: none;
padding:2px;
border: 1px solid white;
border-spacing: 1px;
}
</style>

<ul class="nav1">
<li>one</li>
<li>two<br /> lines</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav2">
<li>one</li>
<li>two<br /> lines</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? The fiddle you linked has a 1px margin between each li.

Comment: margin-right:1px; plus border:1px solid white; equals two pixel gap

Answer (score 0):

You could remove any margin and just assign a right border of 1px to your list items.

```
border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
```

[Here your adjusted jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLDcU/5/).

Alternatively you could assign the border to the left side, and then remove it on the first-child to keep things balanced and looking nice.

```
li:first-of-type {
    border-left: none;
}
```

[Here an example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLDcU/8/) (this time with black background so you can see what is going on).

---

You could also solve this without borders by wrapping the text in another div (or anchor for that matter), applying some padding to the list items, and moving the background to the new inner div. One benefit of this method is that you end up with transparent spaces as you would if you applied margins normally.

So for example:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="inner_wrap">one1</div></li>
    <li><div class="inner_wrap">two2<br /> lines</div></li>
    <li><div class="inner_wrap">three3</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.inner_wrap {
    background-color:#777;
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 1px;
}
li:first-of-type {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Here a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLDcU/10/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a updated JS fiddle for you here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLDcU/6/)

Added and alternated some attributes like margin-right: 1px; to .nav2 li

The border caused that 1px extra space between your li items.

```
.nav1 li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#777;
    margin-right:1px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding:2px;
```

}

```
.nav2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    margin-right:1px;
    background-color:#777;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding:2px;
    margin-right:1px;
```

}